# RAID1 resync doesn't keep syncronized disks when one device was manually changed

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, raid1, md

After some crash on a RAID1 I did some investigation and tests.

Doing the following:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=1 bs=1M count=256
# dd if=/dev/zero of=2 bs=1M count=256
# losetup /dev/loop1 1
# losetup /dev/loop2 2
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 -l 1 -n 2 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/loop2
```

What should happen when the array is assembled again? I would expect 1) some warning en `/proc/mdstat`, or 2) the information on good disk were synced to the randomized disk, or 3) the randomized "bad" disk were synced to the good one.

Only the following is shown on kernel's ring buffer:

```
md/raid1:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
md/raid1:md0: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 268107776
md: resync of RAID array md0
md: md0: resync done.
```

What's that resync? Neither the first drive nor the second one was changed after that resync.

When the array is reassembled, `/proc/mdstat` shows "resync", and seconds after everything is OK with `/proc/mdstat`:

```
md0 : active raid1 loop2[1] loop1[0]
      261824 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Also forcing resync writing to `/sys/devices/virtual/block/md0/md` does any change.

Is that the expected behavior?

I did that tests after a RAID1 experienced a physically bad disk, and the good disk doesn't had any information, but instead only `0x00` and `0x55` bytes.

Comment: Did you try failing, removing, and readding `loop2`?

Comment: Yep. I tried setting `loop2` as faulty and readding it... no differences!

Comment: What I get is `mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop2 [...] has no superblock - assembly aborted`. So it does the right thing - as long as the metadata is gone. It won't detect data modifications while metadata is intact. You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: What kernel version @frostschutz? I'm using 4.14.17-1 amd64 from Debian sid.

Comment: It should be like that for any kernel version really. If you truly stopped the RAID and then `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/loop2` - there is no way it will assemble with metadata gone. Maybe you didn't stop it, then `md` might re-write metadata.

Comment: Ok @frostschutz, you are right; if I assemble the array with `--assemble --scan` after writing the config file it will assemble degraded (only one drive, no metadata on second drive) and that's a trigger for alarms. In my previous tests I did 'recreate' the array with `mdadm --create` again... But in this case, it is OK that the array is being created with the disks not synced anymore?  i.e. `md0` device shows basically what `/dev/loop1` holds regardless that `/dev/loop2` was overwritten and it remains as is, out of sync...

Comment: `mdadm --create` should sync unless you `--assume-clean`. Even if you do `--assume-clean`, data would only be different for "free space" and not things you write after the `--create`. You only get problems if you don't `mkfs` after `mdadm --create`, i.e. if there already was a filesystem on one disk and start using that despite not being redundant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74002/discussion-between-emilio-lazo-and-frostschutz).

Comment: Writing all the array with random data (`dd` to `/dev/md0`) syncronizes both `loop` devices, that's OK but stopping the array and writing some data to a random location on *one* `loop` device does not syncronizes to the other `loop` device when the array is reassembled, even if the resync is forced.